# css - Need alternative way to align 2 elements in one line

Tags: html, css

I need alternative way to make 2 elements (1 align left and 1 align right) in one line. I use `display: flex;` and display correctly on safari on iOS 9 but it won't display correctly on Safari on iOS 6.

It should look like this (iOS 9)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO3RM.jpg

And here is iOS 6
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHK5l.jpg

My CSS code

```
.signedlatest {
   font-family: "sfns_displayregular";
   font-size: 13pt;
   font-color: #ffffff;
   background: #ffffff;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   margin: 0;
   border-top-style: solid;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   border-color: gray;
   border-width: 0.5px;
   line-height: 250%;
   padding-left: 0.3cm;
   padding-right: 0.3cm;
```

}

HTML

```
<div class="signedlatest>
<a>iPhone 6S Plus</a>
<a>iOS 9.3.4</a>
.........
<a>iPhone 4S</a>
<a>iOS 9.3.4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried floating them left and right (and clearing later)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<table>`

```css
table tr td:first-child{
  padding-right:20px;  
}
table tr{
  border-bottom:1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>iPhone 6S Plus</td>
     <td>iOS 9.3.4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>iPhone 6S</td>
     <td>iOS 9.3.4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>iPhone 5</td>
     <td>iOS 9.3.4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
a {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

a:nth-child(2n) {
  text-align: right;
}
```